# How to export git commits to a text file?

Tags: java, git, logging, commit, history

I am using git to manage my Java projects and have committed various changes over the past months.

When using the command 'gitk' I can see the commits done on the repository I am using.I was wondering if there was a way to extract these commits and place them in a text file?

Regards

Comment: [git log](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gitlog to create a history of committed changes. You can set since and until parameters to specify a date range. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

```
$ git log
```